# Fixing the "AttributeError: module 'requests' has no attribute 'methods'" error after reinstalling packages?

Tags: python, flask, request, package

I am attempting to use userName = requests.form.get['username'] to make the variable userName equal to the form input, but I am getting an attribute error in flask

I have: Uninstalled requests and reinstalled the package, installed different versions of the package, installing latest lxml package, checking the python PATH. Every use of the request package is an error yet I pip installed it the same way as my other packages that work well. I am running Python 3.7 and the latest request package through pip install

```
from urllib import request
import random
import requests
import urllib
import time
from datetime import date
import sys
import re
import json
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify


@app.route("/handle_data", methods =['GET', 'POST'])
def handle_data():
    if requests.methods == 'POST':
        userName = requests.form.get['username']
        listName = requests.form.get['listname']

                code here
HTML
<!-- Forms -->
<form action="{{ url_for('handle_data') }}" method="POST">
<form>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col">
      <input type="text" size=15 name=username class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
     </div>
     <div class="col">
      <input type="text" size=15 name=listname class="form-control" placeholder="List Name">
    </div>
  </div>
  <p><input type = "submit" class="buttonclass" value = "Random!" /></p>
</form>
```

I receive an AttributeError.

Comment: You confused the `requests` library with the `request` object from Flask.

Comment: @KlausD. thank you, thank you so much, Klaus. I searched high and low for request tutorials, but they were all for the package. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
userName = requests.form.get['username']
listName = requests.form.get['listname']
```

To

```
userName = request.form.get['username']
listName = request.form.get['listname']
```

requests module and request object (from flask) were confused